# O que é Beacon?

Tags: java, android

O que é Beacon?

Como posso implementado usando Android?

Poder ser implementado em .NET ou só em java?

Tem algum exemplo simples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De maneira similar ao NFC(*Near Field Communication*), os Beacons interagem com *smartphones* quando posicionados num determinado raio de distância usando o *Bluetooth*. Basicamente é um nome amigável para tecnologia ["*indoor proximity system*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system)<sup>en</sup> ou "sistema de proximidade em ambientes fechados".

Na prática, ela permite localizar objetos (ou pessoas que carregam esses objetos) com muito mais precisão dentro de ambientes fechados. Os *Beacons* estão para ambientes fechados assim como o GPS está para ambientes externos.

Para implementação no Android, é necessário dar permissão de acesso ao Bluetooh no seu Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Veja aqui neste artigo sobre [Building an Android Beacon (Android iBeacon Tutorial Overview)](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-14-building-android-beacon-android-ibeacon-tutorial-overview/) uma ideia completa de implementação.

O Google fornece uma biblioteca para implantação usando `.NET`. Veja mais detalhes em [Google Proximity Beacon API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/proximitybeacon/v1beta1).

Comment: Existe outra aplicação ao termo? Poderia (caso sim), acrescentar algo paro o uso : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon

Comment: @MagicHat como na pergunta é questionado "como implementar no Android", acabei seguindo o contexto.

Comment: Ok, mas isso não se aplica a android tmb?

Comment: @MagicHat se aplica no browser, provavelmente, digo provavelmente, se aplica ao Android. Depois dou uma melhorada aqui. =D vlw.