# O que é tracking pixel?

Tags: aplicação-web, terminologia

Recentemente conversara com um amigo a respeito de `tracking pixel`, mas eu não entendi exatamente o que é e como funciona.

Hoje me deparei com a questão, [o que é beacon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227092/o-que-%C3%A9-beacon), e pesquisando cai no conceito de `web beacon`.

Como implemento isso, é no *back-end* ou no *front-end* ou onde e como?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O *beacon* é um guarda-chuva para técnicas de rastreamento, entre elas o *tracking pixel*, que é um mecanismo polêmico porque ele tenta informar sobre o acesso a uma mensagem ou outra forma individual de que a pessoa acessou aquilo.

Alguns consideram uma invasão de privacidade porque não tem como a pessoa saber que esse rastreamento está ocorrendo e não tem muito como se defender sem comprometer funcionalidades normais (tem alguns clientes que já possuem facilidades, mas quase precisa ser técnico para configurar de forma adequada). Claro que uma pessoa com conhecimento técnico e vontade tem o que fazer.

Ele consiste em inserir um pixel invisível que tem algum identificador único, quando o conteúdo for acessado ele será carregado indicando no servidor que houve acesso ao conteúdo e dá para saber quem foi se o identificador for vinculado a uma identidade obtida de outra forma.

Sabe aquele recurso de pedir confirmação se a pessoa leu o e-mail e que pode ser deligado? Alguns clientes nem respondem a isso. O *tracking pixel* funciona sempre, a não ser que a carga de imagens esteja desabilitada. Isto pode ser usado para vários tipos de conteúdo, não só e-mails.

A forma exata de implementação pode variar, pode não ser invisível, pode não ser um pixel, pode não ter um identificador único, depende da necessidade e do que tem a disposição.

Uma forma de ver é tratá-lo como se fosse um *cookie*.

É uma ferramenta técnica basicamente à serviço do marketing, por isso outros detalhes não são importantes no nosso contexto.

Isto é implementado no cliente (uma página HTML em algum lugar), com suporte no servidor se quiser controlar a identidade. Geralmente se acessa o *log* para ver o que foi acessado. Mas pode ter um servidor para lidar com isso de forma específica. O processo é simples e semelhante ao que se usa no *cookie*.

```
<img src="http://tracking.dominio.com/pixel.gif?id=1234"/>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/TrackingPixel.html).

Comment: O que seria esse `guarda-chuva para técnicas`?

Comment: Tem várias maneiras de rastrear, o *pixel tracking* é uma delas, o *beacon* é sobre todas elas.

Comment: @MagicHat viu que eu dei uma editada? Ficou bom agora?